# How to update the field at particular date of month in database

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to give recharge to users at a particular date in every month. I want to use npm package cron to do
that but not getting the way to complete.Do I have to use middleware or any specific route for that.Someone give me a idea to complete that part.I am using node and mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand the problem, if it is finding an npm library or the logical approach, I will try to answer both here.

1. NPM library, try https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron, even though there are very good libraries out there, I suggest going native using OS cron to schedule the jobs
2. Logical Approach:- you need to write the respective logic of finding eligible users to whom you want to process recharge and then asynchronously or synchronously (depends on your business requirement) process recharges, now this job needs to be scheduled if you are using native OS cron help (you will find many tutorials to do same), or if you are using npm library then create a scheduler app which calls your actual app rest will be taken care by the library.

Comment: I want to give 1000 words limit  to  users at a particular date of month . So, how can I do that using npm library.